# Building XHProf into CI (phpundercontrol) non-intrusively

Tags: php, continuous-integration, phpundercontrol, profiling, xhprof

I would love to build XHProf output and metrics into phpUnderControl. After doing a good amount of research, it seems the only path to XHProf is to actually change code to include and execute it. Does XHProf have any modes similar to xdebug's profiler enable trigger where it can profile without modifications? Has anyone produced an automation tool for profiling with a CI server like phpUnderControl or Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use PHP's auto_prepend_file, and auto_append_file in a custom ini to enable and disable the details without modifying the files themselves? I suggest something like that for the GUI: https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof/blob/master/INSTALL

Comment: Great suggestion. It did require some additional work on my application end to behave correctly. Now I'm off to incorporate those results in some flexible metric.